# Can Indy's SMTP Authentication method cause an email to go to the junk box in hotmail?

Tags: delphi, email, indy10

My company has a business app written in Delphi that sends e-mails, it was written on Delphi 7 but we moved to Delphi 2010 earlier this year, due to the port we had to move from Indy 9 to Indy 10.

Before the port we used this code to authenticate on the SMTP server:

```
 ...
 IdSMTP1.AuthenticationType := atLogin;
 IdSMTP1.Username := pUser;
 IdSMTP1.Password := pPassword;
 ...
```

After the port we changed to

```
 ...
 IdSMTP1.AuthType := satDefault;
 IdSMTP1.Username := pUser;
 IdSMTP1.Password := pPassword;
 ...
```

Before the change hotmail put the received e-mails in the inbox, but now it puts them in the junkbox. Can this change in the SMTP Authentication method be the cause of this?

The SMTP server is from my company (ex: smtp.mycompany.com)

Comment: ONe quick thing you can do is check if your address (SMTP.mycompany.com) has entirely valid mail (A) records in the DNS system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code change is not the cause of Hotmail's decision on your company's mails.

Behind the scene, there is a complicated reputation system that evaluates all receiving emails from the sources. I could not find a Hotmail link, but this Exchange article mentions some similar details,

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124512.aspx

From my guess, your company's mail server has been used for some "evil" things, such as sending out junk emails or any others. Hotmail system detects that (or via a third party reputation gateway), so it marks all following mails as junk.

For you, there is no way to change it until the reputation system re-evaluates the mail server.

Comment: Then its just a coincidence: Bad release timing + New Version Syndrom